# PHP Is there a better way to protect my pages than using header(location)?

Tags: php, session, authentication, header, location

I am protecting my pages by checking the values of my sessions. Is there a more secure way of protecting my pages other than changing the Header Location if the sessions are not valid??? Am I doing anything right???

I have the following at the top of each page:

```
<?php
     session_start();

     //VERIFY LOGIN
     $validkey = 'br1ll1ant)=&';

     if ($_SESSION['valid'] != (hash('sha256',$validkey)) && $_SESSION['tokenconfirm'] != hash('sha256',$_SESSION['tokenID']))  {

            header("location:/login/");

         };

?>
```

Comment: Why are you putting hashed values in sessions? It's not like the user can directly access them; and I suppose they would know the values in advance regardless. So what is the point?

Comment: Two side notes: Actually your header() Call is not RFC-Compliant. One should always specify a valid URL with protocoll and hostname.  Regarding the hash in the session: I find this is good practice because that way the session file could be read by an attacker without knowing the password. (An attacker could propably read arbitary files on the system through other errors - just in case!) ;)

Comment: Hashing the password in a session still doesn't change the fact that the password is being stored in plaintext. If a vulnerability allows an attacker to view temporary session variables (which are usually world-readable) the same attacker should be able to read the web root files (which are usually world-readable), including the PHP source containing the password.

Comment: actually, Location header do not protect anything. While script termination does. Note knittl's answer. Grandmaster's one is another way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using `header()` is fine, but don't forget to `exit();` your script after calling `header()`. User agents don't have to respect headers, so one could write a client which will simply read the part that comes after the header call.

```
if(!session_is_valid()) {
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a templating system?  If you are, what you'd do is simply output the login form instead of the page content if the user isnt validated.  Even if you arent using one, you can change the output (different set of includes, for example), if the user isnt valid.  This way you arent relying upon the end user's browser to protect the content.

Answer (score 0):

Headers should be fine, I haven't seen people use much anything else.

It is always best to authenticate to gain access to the page, and then check that authentication on every page. If it fails, redirect to the login.

Using a MVC pattern, it is best to check the login status before they even get to a page, and either redirect if not logged in, or load the logged in view.

Answer (score 0):

Using a front controller pattern you can put all your php files outside the web root. That way they are not directly accessible from a URL. This is fairly common practice in PHP frameworks include those built with Zend 'Framework'.

If your files are in the web root, another method that you might consider is to use constants. This is how CodeIgniter does it. Define a constant in your front controller and if its not defined send them to the web root. Here is how to CI uses constants.

The constant used everywhere

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

How it is defined.

```
define('BASEPATH', $system_folder.'/');
```

$system_folder being a few lines above.

```
$system_folder = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$system_folder;
```

Comment: actually the way to go, but I guess OP's file is meant to be accessed by authenticated users.